# Simple decal system only working in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I develop Web Player application.
In scene i have some 3d model (example: box).
In runtime i upload *.png image an use this image on Decal to my car.
I use this package: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13889 for Decal System.
I Editor work fine, but in runtime i can't use my picture in decal System.
task: need at any time replace a picture and it becomes a good in Decal System.
Please help me.
Thanks!

```
public GameObject decal;
public Material mat;
Texture2D texTmp;
Sprite spr;
string settingsContent;
string[] settingsSplit;

int texWidth,texHeight;

void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadSettings());
}

IEnumerator DownloadSettings()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("http://585649.workwork.web.hosting-test.net/Logo1/settings.txt");
    yield return www;
    settingsContent = www.text;
    settingsSplit = settingsContent.Split('\n');
    if (www.isDone)
    {
        texWidth = int.Parse(settingsSplit[1]);
        texHeight = int.Parse(settingsSplit[2]);
        texTmp = new Texture2D(texWidth,texHeight);
        StartCoroutine(DownloadLogos());
    }
}

IEnumerator DownloadLogos()
{
    WWW www = new WWW(settingsSplit[0]);
    yield return www;
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texTmp);
    if (www.isDone)
    {
        spr = Sprite.Create(texTmp, new Rect(0, 0, texTmp.width, texTmp.height), Vector2.zero, 100);
        spr.texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        mat.mainTexture = spr.texture;
        Color clr = new Color32(255,255,255,255);
        clr.a = float.Parse(settingsSplit[3]);
        mat.color = clr;
        decal.AddComponent("Decal");
        decal.GetComponent<Decal>().material = mat;
        decal.GetComponent<Decal>().sprite = spr;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edit my question (with code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood. Thank you all!

```
public Decal decal;
public Material mat;
Texture2D texTmp;
Sprite spr;
string settingsContent;
string[] settingsSplit;

int texWidth,texHeight;
float sizeX, sizeY;

void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadSettings());
}

IEnumerator DownloadSettings()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("http://sitesman.com/logotypes/Logo1/settings.txt");
    yield return www;
    settingsContent = www.text;
    settingsSplit = settingsContent.Split('\n');
    if (www.isDone)
    {
        texWidth = int.Parse(settingsSplit[1]);
        texHeight = int.Parse(settingsSplit[2]);
        texTmp = new Texture2D(texWidth,texHeight);

        if(texWidth > texHeight)
        {
            sizeX = texWidth / texHeight;
            sizeY = 1;
        }
        else if (texWidth < texHeight)
        {
            sizeX = 1;
            sizeY = texHeight / texWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            sizeX = 1;
            sizeY = 1;
        }

        float multipier = 1;

        if(settingsSplit[4] != null)
        {
            multipier = float.Parse(settingsSplit[4]);
        }

        decal.transform.localScale = new Vector3(sizeX*multipier,sizeY*multipier,2f);

        StartCoroutine(DownloadLogos());
    }
}

IEnumerator DownloadLogos()
{
    WWW www = new WWW(settingsSplit[0]);
    yield return www;
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texTmp);
    if (www.isDone)
    {
        spr = Sprite.Create(texTmp, new Rect(0, 0, texTmp.width, texTmp.height), Vector2.zero, 100);
        spr.texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        mat.mainTexture = spr.texture;
        Color clr = new Color32(255,255,255,255);
        clr.a = float.Parse(settingsSplit[3]);
        mat.color = clr;
        decal.material = mat;
        decal.sprite = spr;
        BuildDecal(decal);
    }
}

GameObject go;
private GameObject[] affectedObjects;

private void BuildDecal(Decal decal)
{
    MeshFilter filter = decal.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    if (filter == null) filter = decal.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
    if (decal.renderer == null) decal.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    decal.renderer.material = decal.material;

    if (decal.material == null || decal.sprite == null)
    {
        filter.mesh = null;
        return;
    }

    affectedObjects = GetAffectedObjects(decal.GetBounds(), decal.affectedLayers);
    foreach (GameObject go in affectedObjects)
    {
        DecalBuilder.BuildDecalForObject(decal, go);
    }
    DecalBuilder.Push(decal.pushDistance);

    Mesh mesh = DecalBuilder.CreateMesh();
    if (mesh != null)
    {
        mesh.name = "DecalMesh";
        filter.mesh = mesh;
    }
}

private static GameObject[] GetAffectedObjects(Bounds bounds, LayerMask affectedLayers)
{
    MeshRenderer[] renderers = (MeshRenderer[])GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MeshRenderer>();
    List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();
    foreach (Renderer r in renderers)
    {
        if (!r.enabled) continue;
       // if (!IsLayerContains(affectedLayers, r.gameObject.layer)) continue;
        if (r.GetComponent<Decal>() != null) continue;

        if (bounds.Intersects(r.bounds))
        {
            objects.Add(r.gameObject);
        }
    }
    return objects.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Import into Unity the free asset 'Basic Decal System' from the following link or via the Unity Asset Store.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/simple-decal-system-13889

Prepare a suitable image for the decal with transparency if required. Save the file in TARGA (.tga) format and import into Unity in a suitable location.

*** Note. It is neater to create one image file containing a sheet of the images to use as decals.

Create Sprites from the Image
Select the image file in Assets and in the inspector change the Texture type to Sprite(2D and UI) and press apply.

From the inspector if the image file only contains one image, select Single for the sprite mode. If you have created a sheet of images then select Multiple, You can then select 'Sprite Editor' and create multiple sprites by drawing bounds around each image on the sheet of images and providing suitable names. The sprites will appear in a fly out under the original image.

Create a Material
Create a new material. Then name of the material must begin with 'Decal'. In the inspector, change the shader to 'Legacy Shaders/Transparency/Diffuse', then click on 'Select' and select the image containing the sprites.

Creating the Decal
Create a Cube in the scene, rename to a suitable name and from Assets>DecalSystem>Plugins>Decalsystem, drop the script 'Decal' onto the Cube. The cube will now be a wire-frame appearance. From the inspector in the Decal Script section, Select the material created earlier and then select the sprite from the drop downs.

Position the cube against the mesh to be projected upon (you may have to rotate the cube to align the projection face).

The decals do not render at runtime. To get the decals to render follow the next steps.

Create an empty gameobject and rename it relating to the decal with a 'Pos' suffix. select the decal cube object then click on the settings icon in the transform section of the inspector and copy the component. Select the empty game object and then click on the settings icon in the transform section of the inspector and paste the component values then change the xyz scale values to '1'. In the hierarchy drop the decal cube object onto the empty position object.

Select the empty position object and from the inspector click the add component and select the 'Decal_Script' script. Decal_Script

In the inspector, drag (or select from the button on the right) the Decal Cube object to the 'This Decal' box.

The decals should now appear at runtime.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using DecalSystem;

public class Decal_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject ThisDecal;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

         CreatePrefab();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void CreatePrefab()
    {
       // instantiate decal

        GameObject obj = Instantiate(ThisDecal, ThisDecal.transform.position, ThisDecal.transform.rotation);

        //decal implementation!!
        var decal = obj.GetComponent<Decal>();
        if (decal) //if this obj has decal script
        {
            var filter = decal.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            var mesh = filter.mesh;
            if (mesh != null)
            {
                mesh.name = "DecalMesh";
                filter.mesh = mesh;
            }
            DecalBuilder.Build(decal);

        }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to build upon @NoIQ's answer and create something a little more portable:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/*
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28603035/3990396
*/
public class DecalDynamic {
    public static void BuildDecal(Decal decal) {
        MeshFilter filter = decal.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if (filter == null) filter = decal.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if (decal.GetComponent<Renderer>() == null) decal.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        decal.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = decal.material;

        if (decal.material == null || decal.sprite == null) {
            filter.mesh = null;
            return;
        }

        GameObject[] affectedObjects = GetAffectedObjects(decal.GetBounds(), decal.affectedLayers);
        foreach (GameObject go in affectedObjects) {
            DecalBuilder.BuildDecalForObject(decal, go);
        }
        DecalBuilder.Push(decal.pushDistance);

        Mesh mesh = DecalBuilder.CreateMesh();
        if (mesh != null) {
            mesh.name = "DecalMesh";
            filter.mesh = mesh;
        }
    }

    public static GameObject[] GetAffectedObjects(Bounds bounds, LayerMask affectedLayers) {
        MeshRenderer[] renderers = (MeshRenderer[])GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<MeshRenderer>();
        List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (Renderer r in renderers) {
            if (!r.enabled || r.GetComponent<Decal>() != null) continue;
            if (bounds.Intersects(r.bounds)) objects.Add(r.gameObject);
        }
        return objects.ToArray();
    }
}
```

To use, you need to move the scripts inside the Editor folder to the parent directory. Here is how I'm using the script to add dynamic gun decals:

```
GameObject decal = Instantiate(prefab, col.contacts[0].point, Quaternion.Euler(col.contacts[0].normal));
DecalDynamic.BuildDecal(decal.GetComponent<Decal>());
```